# hey so I am making a form for text submission for a website and I dont know how to collect the text inputted by the user

Tags: html, backend

Here is my code so far

```
<form action="/sugggest-list" method="post" id="form" name="form">
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" rows="20" cols="100">Input feedback here</textarea>
<div class="button">
  <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</div>
</form>
```

disclaimer:

While searching the internet I didn't find anything relevant to the backend part and I also dont know back end web stuff

Comment: There are _tons_ of back-end technologies and techniques available so this may be too broad of a question for some good answers.

Comment: thanks for the input, but asking how to do something and only being told there is a ton of ways to do it doesn't help too much

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed around asking specific questions, especially "this thing I'm trying isn't working; how can I fix it," not so much open-ended questions. These constraints and the number of unknowns here make this a difficult question to answer. A discussion forum or chat platform, not a Q&A site, would be a better help because an expert in the subject would need to prompt you with many follow up questions to suss out exactly what you need, and there's also tons of subjectivity involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a back-end "webserver" on your own local computer with NodeJS or PHP.

The action="" part of the tag has to be a valid URL that points to part of the backend.

The name="" part of any input or textara tag is the name that the backend will identify that input with.

If you're just trying to get something quick working without a backend you could try using a "mailto" url to send an email
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-mailto-forms.html